# Which packages to install on web server?

Tags: web-server

I have a debian 6 server. I want to know which packages I should install for a production web server? Maybe some advices on configuring production web server. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is way too vague -- we have no idea what kind of service you are going to run. Do you need PHP? If, what PHP modules you need? Do you need Python/Java? Will it be a high-traffic site needing something like Varnish and memcached? Do you use database? If, what? And so on... the question list is endless.

Answer (score 1):

Only those which you will actually need. Keeping unneeded services off a production server is just one of the ways of making sure things run smoothly.